# Create a dictionary from SQL query results

Tags: python, sql

I need to create a dictionary from list of tuples. SQL query returns something like this
`[['a',5], ['b',8], ['c',10]]`

Is it possible to use python the `dict()` constructor ?

Comment: It took you longer to write this post than it would have taken you to type `dict([['a',5],['b',8],['c',10]])` in a console.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and try:

```
dict([['a',5] , ['b',8] , ['c',10]])
```

on your favourite python console.
You'll notice: it works.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) tell you why:

> dict(iterable, **kwarg)
>
> Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
>   objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
>   dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

This obviously is under the assumption that a, b and c are what you actually wanted as keys in the dictionary.